# Como chamar um ID no HTML mais de uma vez?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como chamar um id mais de uma vez ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Agenda</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
</head>
<style>
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
    color: white;
}

.closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
<!--
.esconde{
display:none;
}-->
.aparece{
display:inline;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function muda(){
    classe = document.getElementById('tst').className; 
    if(classe == 'esconde'){
       document.getElementById('tst').className = 'aparece';
   }else{
       document.getElementById('tst').className = 'esconde';
   }
}
//-->
</script>

<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "agenda";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
$consulta = $_GET['consulta'];
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, NOME, EMAIL, TELEFONE, TELEFONE2, TELEFONE3, TELEFONE4, EMPRESA, ENDERECO FROM contatos WHERE `contatos`.`NOME` LIKE  '$consulta'");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>
<body background="img/BH (1192)2.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;">
   <div class="form-group w3-padding-32 w3-content">
   <a href="cadastro.html" ><button class="btn btn-success center">Novo Contato</button></a>
   <a onClick="document.location.reload(true)" ><button  class="btn btn-info center">Atualizar</button></a>
   <a onClick="muda();"><button class="btn btn-warning center">Editar</button></a>
   <a href="../choice.html" ><button class="btn btn-danger center">Sair</button></a>
</div>
<div class="esconde" id="tst">
<div class="alert w3-content">
  O Modo de edição está <strong> ATIVO </strong>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group w3-padding-32 w3-content">
<div class=" w3-container w3-content">
<br>
<form method="GET" action="busca.php?consulta=<?$consulta?>">
<label for="consulta"><font color="#ffffff">Buscar:</font></label>
<input type="text" value="<?=$consulta?>" id="consulta" name="consulta" maxlength="255" required />
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-table-all w3-container w3-card">
<table border=1 style="font-size:11px;width:1280px">
   <tr>
   <th>Nome</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Telefones</th>
   <th>Empresa</th>
   <th>Endereço</th>
   <div class="esconde" id="tst">
   <th>Deletar</th>
   <th>Editar</th>
   </div>
   </tr>
<?php
 // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
 if($total > 0) {
  // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
  do {

?>

   <tr>
   <td><?=$linha['NOME']?></td>
   <td><?=$linha['EMAIL']?></td>
   <td><?=$linha['TELEFONE']?><br>
   <?=$linha['TELEFONE2']?><br>
   <?=$linha['TELEFONE3']?><br>
   <?=$linha['TELEFONE4']?></td>
   <td><?=$linha['EMPRESA']?></td>
   <td><?=$linha['ENDERECO']?></td>
   <div class="esconde" id="tst">
  <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript: if (confirm('Você realmente deseja excluir este Contato ?'))location.href='excluir.php?id=<?=$linha['id']?>'" style="margin-left:13px"><i class="fa fa-trash-o w3-xlarge"></i></a></td>
   <td><a href="#" onclick="javascript: location.href='troca.php?id=<?=$linha['id']?>'" style="margin-left:13px"><i class="fa fa-pencil w3-xlarge"></i></a></td>
   </div>
         </tr>
<?php   
  // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
  }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
 // fim do if 
 }
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Nesta página o id **tst** só é exibido quando clicar em editar, porém não é possível chamar o id mais de uma vez. Soluções?

PS: Ignorem a parte de PHP E Mysql

Comment: Por qual motivo quer chamar mais de uma vez?

Comment: Troque o ID para class, qual a necessidade de chama-lo mais de uma vez? explique melhor sua duvida

Comment: Para fazer outras partes desaparecerem também que no caso é o editar e excluir no final da tabela............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs são atributos que **não podem** ser repetidos, isto porque ID significa "Identidade", ou seja dois elementos **não podem** ter a mesma identidade.

Talvez o ideal seria criar um ID para cada um, para ajustar você pode trocar o getElementById por outro atributo qualquer, como um atributo customizado HTML5 chamado `data-`, vamos chamado de `data-toggle="..."`, a função deve ficar assim:

```
var modoedicao = false; //Inicia como false, modo edição "desligado"

function muda(id){
   modoedicao = !modoedicao;//Alterna entre edição e leitura

   var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]');

   for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (modoedicao) {
           array[i].className = 'aparece';
        } else {
           array[i].className = 'esconde';
        }
   }
}
```

E os elementos HTML devem ficar assim:

```
<div class="esconde" data-toggle="tst">
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo aqui funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado........